# webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync().Wait() freezes the UI

Tags: silverlight-4.0, task, parallel-processing, async-ctp

I am using silverlight 4, and the new async CTP.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient wb = new WebClient();
            var t = wb.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.google.com");
            t.Wait();            
        }
```

This code causes the UI to freeze.
On the other hand, this code works fine :

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient wb = new WebClient();
            var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Debug.WriteLine("Doing something"));
            t.Wait();            
        }
```

Whats the difference between the two, and what causes the first one to freeze ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.Wait()` blocks on the Task until it has completed.

The first example does actual work, i.e. fetches *www.google.com* and with `.Wait()` will not allow the event handler to return until that page has been downloaded.

The second example merely calls `Debug.WriteLine`, i.e. a call that returns immediately, allowing the Task to complete immediately, so you never noticed that `.Wait()` is blocking the event handler.

Most likely you'll want to use `.ContinueWith()` instead of `.Wait()` to access the result from the async download. That way the event handler immediately returns and you can put code in the `.ContinueWith()` block to do something with the data downloaded.

Comment: But the first example never finishes. It's stuck. why is that ?

Comment: When i run that code it returns almost immediately. Best bet is a networking problem that stops the request from ever connecting. A proxy pointing at the wrong server, bad dns, not sure.