# Getting RavenDB Client API to work in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, ravendb

I just learned that RavenHQ is an easy-to-use database for .NET and especially Silverlight. I'm trying to insert some Test Data (see Code) but it won’t work. I think I am missing something big because I'm new to RavenDB.

I added the references to the project and created clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml. I get (Firebug) an HTTP 200 Response to "GET clientaccesspolicy.xml" from 1.ravenhq.com but nothing else happens and no data is inserted. Any Ideas would be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub TestRavenDB()
    Try
        Dim ds = New DocumentStore()
        ds.Url = "https://1.ravenhq.com/databases/AppHarbor_60e82bd1-234f-4178-a59a-b527a1d391bb"
        ds.ApiKey = "1f827c44-3e38-4e66-8801-83ba03b01f67"
        ds.Initialize()

        Dim p As New Person("Donald")
        Dim session As IAsyncDocumentSession = ds.OpenAsyncSession()
        session.Store(p)

        session.SaveChangesAsync()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have `SaveChangesAsync` there. Before your test return, you need to wait for that to complete.

Comment: I figured something like that. How would i implement the wait? a delegate and BeginInvoke?

Comment: session.SaveChangesAsync().Wait()

Comment: Thanks for you fast answers. session.SaveChangesAsync().Wait() freezes the whole browser, not sure why. I think ist because Silverlight only has one (UI) thread. There should be a solution, since RavenHQ uses Silverlight for managing Databases.

Comment: Tried session.SaveChangesAsync().Wait() via Dispatcher.InvokeAsync and BeginInvoke, still freezes.                                     Dim th As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf TestRavenDB)) doesn't change anything either..

Comment: This is how you handle async tests: http://ayende.com/blog/141313/async-tests-in-silverlight

Comment: The root post: http://devlicio.us/blogs/christopher_bennage/archive/2011/01/17/improving-asynchronous-tests-for-silverlight.aspx

Comment: And here is how you can do it without the custom extension: http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/03/asynchronous-testing/

Comment: I think the Name "TestRavenDB()" may be misleading, i'm just trying to post some data, not testing like a unit test (It'still going to be useful later). I'm still stuck at how to wait for SaveChangesAsync() since BeginInvoke doesn't do it and .wait freezes everything (because single SL UI Thread). Which construct do i have to use to make a simple async-call like save? It shouldn't be much code, should it?

Comment: As per usual, the problem is a different one, than expected. I understood that .wait (or .continuewith) were the right commands. The freezing (and no data inserting) is caused by some unrelated error connecting to the server similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892689/webclient-downloadstringtaskasync-wait-freezes-the-ui